# When drawing an NSString with -drawAtPoint:, what is the starting point of the string?

Tags: iphone

Relative to the text... where is the point? Top left of the rectangle where the text is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Parameters**
>
> *point*
>
> The location (in the
>   coordinate system of the current
>   graphics context) at which to draw the
>   string. This point represents the
>   top-left corner of the string’s
>   bounding box.